# Error using random raster for raster calculations

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcgis-pro, map-algebra

I have created a random raster in ArcGIS Pro using the following Python command:

```
arcpy.CreateRandomRaster_management(Path, "rnraster", "INTEGER", "", 10)
```

Which works fine.

Performing map algebra operations on this raster is possible when the second parameter is an integer such as:

```
addition = Plus("rnraster", 6)
```

***However***, performing operations that involve any existing raster fail with an enexpected error, such as when I try to add this random raster to my elevation raster/DEM:

```
addition = Plus("rnraster", "elevdata")
OR
addition = Raster("rnraster") + Raster("elevdata")
```

I know that the elevdata raster works in map algebra expressions with other rasters, so my question is:

**What must I do to the randomly generated raster to enable map algebra operations with existing rasters?**

I have already tried matching bit depth, cell size and raster format (16 bit unsigned, 10 and Esri Grid respectively). Does the random raster require spatial referencing first?

Error Log:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Monte Carlo Simulation.py", line 29, in <module>
    demError = arcpy.Raster("elevdata") + arcpy.Raster(rnRaster)
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 4328, in Plus
    in_raster_or_constant2)
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Utils.py", line 53, in swapper
    result = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 4325, in Wrapper
    ["Plus", in_raster_or_constant1, in_raster_or_constant2])
RuntimeError:  ERROR 999998: Unexpected Error.
Failed to execute (MonteCarloSim)
```

Elevation Data Raster Properties:

[image]

Random Raster Properties:

[image]

The random raster has no coordinate system or projection set, whereas the elevation raster does, but would this cause the problem?

Comment: Is that all it says, "Unknown Error"?

Comment: Make that "Unexpected error", even after changing the command to "demError = arcpy.Raster("elevdata") + arcpy.Raster("rnRaster")". I have added the full error to the question.

Comment: Does it work in ArcMap or same error?

Comment: Same error in both ArcMap and an independent IDE, thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: I can't test this Pro right now, but I can use Plus("random","elevation") in ArcMap, so I'm guessing it's a data issue. Are both similarly projected?

Comment: The random raster has no projection, please see edits when convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that trying to add two rasters together that don't have the same coordinate system is what's causing your problem.

When you create your random raster, set the coordinate system in the **[environment settings](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/environments/output-coordinate-system.htm)** of the tool. Alternatively, you could try **[defining a projection](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/define-projection.htm)** on your existing random raster.

Comment: You were spot on, specifically it seems the *extent* of the random raster needed to match, which is perfectly logical now I think about it! Thanks for the assistance.